# Good combination of ships for dualboxed exploration

Tags: eve-online

Currently I'm running with a Myrmidon that can do all sites except gravimetric and wspace.  On the other account I'm using a Manticore for probing and some extra DPS.

What other combinations are considered good?

Answer (score 1):

Like everything with EVE, I think this is going to be highly dependent on your skills.  That said, drones ships aren't always the best for running wspace sites since wspace rats will aggro drones.  For a combat ship, something that isn't highly dependent on cap seems to be a good choice, however.  Some wspace sites will neut, so a ship with a good shield buffer and either missiles or projectile turrets will be somewhat more successful.  Missiles and projectile turrets will continue to fire without capacitor, so you can still deal damage if a rat caps you out.  Buffer tank means you won't have to rely on capacitor to maintain your tank.  Shield tank means you won't need to spend ISK to repair your tank.  Bear in mind that, should you decide to enter a C1 wormhole, you won't be able to bring in anything larger than battlecruiser sized ships.

These days when I explore, I'm looking for wormhole PVP just as much as I'm looking for anomalies to run, so my combat ship of choice has become a PVP fit Nighthawk.  It will dish out approximately 600 dps with Heavy Missiles and drones and comes with a fair bit of EHP.  The combination of tank plus DPS means that it will run most high sec anomalies without any trouble.  That said, a PVE Nighthawk can solo anomalies in C1 and C2's without any trouble.

For a scan ship, I use a Cheetah on my other toon.  I prefer the cheetah since I can fit a salvager in the high slot and a hacking module and analyzer in the mid slots.  This means that I won't have to refit in between high sec anomalies.  And while a Manticore is a valid choice, just keep in mind that your torps will be next to useless against any frigs you may encounter in an anomaly.  Lastly, for those rare occasions where I encounter a high sec anomaly that the Nighthawk is too large to enter into, if I'm not too far from home, I'll swap out to a Gila for cruiser hull or an Ishkur for frigate hull.

Which two ships you chose, however, will always be dependent on your skills more than anything.  I would just say that the two key things to remember are to use a scan ship with enough slots so that you don't have to refit, and a shield and missile/projectile turret combat ship in order to be the most resistant to rats that might neutralize your capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

In wormholes specifically, a good combination is one toon in an orca, other toon flies combat, salvaging, and scanning ship. I won't talk about specific fits here, as that's probably deserving of it's own question.

The Orca means you can just cloak up or go offline in any wormhole, while the combat/salvaging/scanning alt does all of the other things. Swap ships out in the Orca when necessary to do the other tasks.
As for what to keep in the Orca, a T2 or T3 Cruiser (whatever you're skilled for, but T3 Cruiser would be best to aim for) would work well as a combat ship for up to a Class 3 Wormhole, maybe C4 with a more expensive T3 ship, salvaging destroyer, and covert ops frigate of whatever race you're skilled with. Maybe even a stealth bomber or two for if you see an unguarded ship salvaging or a hauler collecting material from Customs Offices.

Having the Orca alt also means you have somewhere safe(ish) to store loot, which can't be shot at while you're offline unlike a Player Owned Starbase. I'd recommend fitting a cloak, and a probe launcher to the Orca (just in case the covops frigate dies or the combat alt gets seperated, i.e. ambushed in a site, and podded back to k-space)

Comment: I didn't know CapShip could jump through WH... Or is the Orca the only one who can do so?

Comment: The Orca is a special capital. Like Freighters and Jump Freighters it's able to pass stargates, so I don't think there's anything keeping it from entering wormholes.

Comment: @Mario, that depends entirely upon the specific wormhole. WHs are different from gates as they are governed by [mass limits](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Wormhole#Wormhole_Identification). The Orca masses 250 Gg (Gigagrams, 1,000,000 kg), so C1s are completely out.